# How the virus got to the WordPress (uniq/load.php -> crypted120med.exe)?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, port

When I go to the

```
http:// MY_IP :8080/uniq/load.php
```

or

```
http:// MY_DOMAIN :8080/uniq/load.php
```

[image]

But when I go to the

```
http:// MY_DOMAIN/uniq/load.php
```

Page 404

Folder **/uniq/** on the server does not.

```
~# find / -name "load.php" -print
/home/site/wp-includes/load.php
```

Where can I find this file? How do I remove this virus?

**UPD:**

```
~# netstat -anop | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1798/sendmail: MTA: off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9312          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1983/searchd     off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1839/mysqld      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1798/sendmail: MTA: off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24312/nginx.conf off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17574/ld-linux.so.2 off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1996/sshd        off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      24312/nginx.conf off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      1405/proftpd: (acce off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1996/sshd        off (0.00/0/0)
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1515747955 1364/php-fpm.conf)  /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1515750299 1839/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1515748802 1798/sendmail: MTA: /var/run/sendmail/mta/smcontrol
```

**Temporary solution**

```
~# kill 17574
```

**Solution**

https://www.debian-administration.org/article/57/Making_/tmp_non-executable

Comment: Since the virus is showing on port 8080, perhaps there is another server process running that listens on that port and serves the request.  Run `netstat -ano | grep LISTEN` on linux to see what is listening on port 8080, find the process and go from there.

Comment: @drew010 Thanks for the answer. However, I do not see anything unusual. Updated question.

Comment: So there is a separate process listening on port 8080.  Forgot to mention to use `netstat -anop` to get the process ID and name of the process running on 8080.

Comment: Thx, I `kill 17574` You do not know the solution to this does not happen again in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with a hacked WordPress site can be very difficult if you have no backups.

WordPress often gets compromised via malicious file uploads allowing remote users to add new files to the system among many other things (cron jobs, malicious binaries etc).

Based on the output of `netstat -anop` that you ran, we are able to see a process running that is listening on port 8080 on your server.  The process in question is `ld-linux.so.2` which was most likely uploaded to your server, or possibly compiled on your system through a malicious shell.  Find this file and get rid of it.  If you can find out how it got there by going through access logs, even better.  This might reveal the exploitation vector.

I've seen a lot of PHP shell backdoors that get uploaded to servers that attackers can control remotely by sending them HTTP requests.

Step 1: Replace all WordPress files with a freshly downloaded copy of WordPress (just download from `http://wordpress.org/latest.zip` and upload everything to your WordPress site root.  This will make sure any modified WP files are restored.

Step 2: Search for malicious files.  This command can be helpful in finding PHP shell scripts: `grep -E '(?:(shell_)?exec|system|eval)' /path/to/wordpress/* -R`  Examine any files it finds and determine if they should be deleted.

Step 3: If step 2 turns up any hits, search your server access logs for requests to those files, and then search the access logs for the IP address that accessed them to see if there is anything else that should be deleted.

Now might be a good time to cycle your logs so you start fresh and can continue to examine them over the coming days to see if they try to strike again.

Step 4: Look for cronjobs that may have been created by the attackers to run scheduled tasks.  You only need to look at the cronjobs your website user has permission to access.  I've seen these scripts create cron jobs to execute tasks or restart malicious files periodically.

Step 5: ...this is by no means a complete list but a start.

If you don't have WP backups (database and files) it may be a lost cause.  If you don't find the exploit, attackers can continue to run code on your site and upload new exploits.

Comment: Thank you.
I put nginx to listen on port 8080.
The file in the folder /tmp/.estbuild/lib/ld-linux.so.2